# Is sentinel node exactly dummy node?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, nodes, sentinel

Let us say in a linked list, many leetcode solutions suggest that we can create a dummy node to make a problem easier ( dummy_node = ListNode(0) ). My DS&A professor also recommends us to have a sentinel node pointing to the head of the linked list. I wonder are they talking about the same thing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This can only be answered either by Leetcode or by the professor or both.

Comment: *"Many leetcode solutions suggest..."*: please complete your question by providing code that demonstrates the use of such a node. We cannot assume that *all* LeetCode solutions that create a dummy node are all using that node in the same way. Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

The term sentinel node I heard is from CS61B. They mean exactly the same thing.

However, since a lot of people don't know what sentinel is(I forget the leetcode question number, but the hottest comment of a linked list problem solution is like, "wow, I have solved so many linked list problems using dummy node without knowing it is called sentinel"), I will continue using the term dummy or dummy_node